Just a simple algebra question
So I have this question: Solve: x = 3y,
(a) x + y + z = 56,
(b) x - 2y - 3z = -25
So you can substitute 3y for x to then eliminate the z by multiplying (a) by -3z then solve accordingly and you get z = 4, y = 13 and x = 39. However my answer key says that you have to eliminate the y by multiplying (b) by -4 (after substituting 3y for x) which results in z = 12, y = 11 and x = 33.
So my question is: is there a certain way these types of equations must be done, or could both answers be correct?

"By multiplying (a) by -3z"?  What do you mean by this and why should this help you solve?

The [education] tag is meant to be used for questions about education... such as "how frequently should tests be administered" or "how do I help students understand the importance of homework".  It is not meant for questions that occurred as a part of your education.

The punchline is that so long as you make progress towards the final goal using legal logical steps towards said goal, you can perform substitutions or cancellations or the like in whatever order and the final answer should always be the same.  The answer key is correct and your answer is incorrect.  I expect you have read the equation (b) incorrectly somehow.  Your answer of $x=39,~y=13,~z=4$ does match the first two equations but fails to match the third equation.  Perhaps you missed the $-25$ there and used $x-2y-3z=1$ instead of $x-2y-3z=-25$ as you should have.
"Is there a certain way these types of equations must be done"  Again, no... so long as you correctly and without error continually make progress towards a final answer you could do this in many different ways... but there does exist an unambiguous way that will always work if you wish to follow the prescribed algorithm to a T.  Read more if you like at wikipedia or in your textbook.

Oh! Right. I see it now. Thanks!

When working with linear systems there are three scenarios regarding the solution:

There are no solutions
There are infinitely many solutions
There is exactly one solution

Therefore it is impossible for both the solution you found and the one given in the answer key to be true. Remember you can always check your answers by plugging in solutions!
There is no way it must be done, as multiple methods lead to the same result, but there is a failproof way to solve linear systems called Gaussian Elimination. Here's a quick example using your question:
$$x - 3y +0z = 0$$
$$x + y + z = 56$$
$$x -2y -3z = -25$$
We take these given equations and express them as a coefficient matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 56 \\
1 & -2 & -3 & -25 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
After applying the necessary row operations the resulting matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 33 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 11 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Leaving us with:
$$x = 33$$
$$y = 11$$
$$z = 12$$
Which can be checked by plugging these values back into the original system. If you want to learn more about Gaussian Elimination there is no shortage of resources on the subject.
